# Can't retrieve data entered in first empty row of grid view

Tags: asp.net

I have placed grid view in update panel with first row as empty and it is not bound with any data base. Rather I have bound grid view with data table. Whenever I click on 'Add New Row' button, a new row is created in grid view there by retaining the data field in old rows but my problem is whenever I click on save button, at that time data of first row is not retried but I can get the data that is filled in second row and onwards. I have saved my data table in session and again retrieving it after each post back.

Here is the code of my .aspx.cs page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using AppResumeMaster;
using System.Collections;
using AppQualificationDetail;


public partial class Applicant_ApplicationForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int Rows = 1;
    object MaxAppId = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            setInitialRow();
        }   
    }
    protected void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            using (DataOperation oDo = new DataOperation())
            {
                MaxAppId= oDo.ExecuteScaler("select max(AppId) from tblAppResumeMaster");
                if (MaxAppId == System.DBNull.Value)
                    MaxAppId = 0;
            }

            using (AppResumeMasterClass objAppResumeMasterClass = new AppResumeMasterClass())
            {
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppId = Convert.ToInt32(MaxAppId)+1;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppFirstName = firstnameBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppLastName = lastnameBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppAddress1 = CurAddBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppCity1 = CurAddBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppState1 = CurStateBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppCountry1 = CurCountrybox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppAddress2 = PerAddBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppCity2 = PerCityBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppState2 = PerStateBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppCountry2 = PerCountrybox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppEmail1 = emailBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppEmail2 = AltEmailBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppMobileNo = mobileNoBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppContactNo = phoneNoBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppDOB = Convert.ToDateTime(birthDateBox.Text);
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppKeySkill = skillsBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppGoal = goalBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppWeakness = weaknessBox.Text;
                objAppResumeMasterClass.AppStrengths = strengthsBox.Text;

                objAppResumeMasterClass.setVal(1);
            }

            DataTable Table = (DataTable)Session["CurTable"];
            int cnt = Table.Rows.Count;
            using(AppQualificationDetailClass objAppQualificationDetail = new AppQualificationDetailClass())
            {
                for (int RowCnt = 0; RowCnt < Table.Rows.Count; RowCnt++)
                {
                    objAppQualificationDetail.AppId = Convert.ToInt32(MaxAppId) + 1;
                    objAppQualificationDetail.QualiId = Convert.ToInt32(Table.Rows[RowCnt][1]);
                    objAppQualificationDetail.Year = Convert.ToInt32(Table.Rows[RowCnt][3]);
                    objAppQualificationDetail.Percentage = (float)Table.Rows[RowCnt][2];
                    objAppQualificationDetail.InstiName = Table.Rows[RowCnt][4].ToString();


                    objAppQualificationDetail.setVal(1);
                }

            }
             ExistMsgLbl.Text = Table.Rows[0][2].ToString();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }   
    }
    protected void addRowBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRow();
    }
    protected void InstituteLbl_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Session.Add("Table", Table1);
    }
    public void setInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable Table = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        Table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qualification",typeof(string)));

        Table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("QualiId",typeof(string)));

        Table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Percentage",typeof(string)));
        Table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Passing Year",typeof(string)));
        Table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Institute Name",typeof(string)));
        dr = Table.NewRow();

        dr["Percentage"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Passing Year"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Institute Name"]=string.Empty;

        Table.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session.Add("CurTable", Table);
        GridView1.DataSource = Table;
        GridView1.DataBind();


        ArrayList Array = new ArrayList();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DropDownList DDL = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("QualificationList");
        FillDropDownList(DDL);
        }
    public void AddNewRow()
    {
        DataSet ds=new DataSet();

        int RowIndex = 0;
        if (Session["CurTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable CurTable = (DataTable)Session["CurTable"];
            DataRow CurRow = null;
            if (CurTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                CurRow = CurTable.NewRow();
                CurTable.Rows.Add(CurRow);
                Session.Add("CurTable", CurTable);
                for (int count = 0; count < CurTable.Rows.Count - 1; count++)
                {
                    DropDownList DDL = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[count].Cells[0].FindControl("QualificationList");
                    TextBox PercentageBox = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[count].Cells[1].FindControl("percentageBox");
                    TextBox yearBox = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[count].Cells[1].FindControl("yearBox");
                    TextBox InstituteNameBox = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[count].Cells[1].FindControl("InstituteNameBox");

                    CurTable.Rows[count]["Percentage"] = PercentageBox.Text;
                    CurTable.Rows[count]["Passing Year"]=yearBox.Text;
                    CurTable.Rows[count]["Institute Name"]=InstituteNameBox.Text;
                    CurTable.Rows[count]["Qualification"]=DDL.SelectedItem.Text;
                    CurTable.Rows[count]["QualiId"] = DDL.SelectedValue;
                }

                GridView1.DataSource = CurTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
        }
        setPreviousData();
    }
    public void setPreviousData()
    {
        int RowIndex = 0;
        if (Session["CurTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable RestoreTable = (DataTable)Session["CurTable"];
            if (RestoreTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < RestoreTable.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    DropDownList DPList = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].FindControl("QualificationList");
                    TextBox PercentageBox = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].FindControl("percentageBox");
                    TextBox YearBox = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[2].FindControl("yearBox");
                    TextBox InstituteName = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].FindControl("InstituteNamebox");

                    FillDropDownList(DPList);

                    if (row < RestoreTable.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        PercentageBox.Text = RestoreTable.Rows[row]["Percentage"].ToString();
                        YearBox.Text = RestoreTable.Rows[row]["Passing Year"].ToString();
                        InstituteName.Text = RestoreTable.Rows[row]["Institute Name"].ToString();

                        DPList.ClearSelection();
                        DPList.Items.FindByText(RestoreTable.Rows[row]["Qualification"].ToString()).Selected = true;
                    }
                    RowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private ArrayList FillArrayList()
    {
        ArrayList ArrayList = new ArrayList();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
          using(DataOperation oDo = new DataOperation())
          {
            ds =oDo.DropDownList("select * from tblQualificationMaster");
            for(int count=0;count<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;count++)
            {
                ArrayList.Add(new ListItem(ds.Tables[0].Rows[count][1].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[count][0].ToString()));
            }
         }
          return ArrayList;
    }
    private void FillDropDownList(DropDownList DDL)
    {
        ArrayList ArrayList = FillArrayList();
        foreach (ListItem item in ArrayList)
        {
            DDL.Items.Add(item);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ViewState instead of Session.